# How to solve the error: cannot find symbol class Set

Tags: java, sudoku

```
import java.io.*;

public class Sudoku
{

    static Set empty = new Set(9);
    static Set fullSet;
    static int [][] board;
    static Set [][] allowedSets;
    ...
}
```

It's just a part of the code.

My problem is:
Sometimes it shows me cannot find symbol class Set and sometimes it shows me that it is an abstract class and can't be instantiated.

I want to create a board [9]x[9]

Comment: And many other warning messages, I expect.

Comment: Only sometimes? Really?

Answer (score 3):

Cyneon,
I believe your problem is that you are not importing the correct Set class. 
You are attempting to create the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) `Set` which is located in java.util.Set.

Therefore, add the `import java.util.Set;` at the top of your class and instantiate the Set using an implementation of the Set interface, such as [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).
Note that if you use HashSet you will also need to import it before use as well, so include `import java.util.HashSet`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate a Set (`new Set(9)`) because it is an interface. You can however instantiate one of its implementations, say `HashSet`, and affect that object to a variable of type `Set` :

```
static Set empty = new HashSet(9);
```

If you have `cannot find symbol class` errors, it must be that you didn't add the relevant imports. You might want to `import java.util.Set` and `import java.util.HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Set is an interface, interfaces can't be instantiated you could implement one of these: HashSet, TreeSet and LinkedHashSet. 
for example in this way:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
```

Here is the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html